# What is the difference between 'Hive on Spark mode' and 'Spark SQL'? Will 'Hive on Spark mode' uses Catalyst Optimizer?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

- Hive on Spark mode vs MR mode
- Spark SQL
- Catalyst Optimizer/RDD/Tungsten

Comment: You should be using Hive on Tez rather than MR mode anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Hive on Spark is different from running Hive queries using Spark SQL via HiveContext. It doesn't translate the queries to Spark primitives but translates them to MapReduce primitives and executes on Spark.Its main purpose to utilize Spark exeuction engine, without impacting existing code in Hive.

Internally, it translates Hive's logical operators to Spark Tasks , which are mostly RDD transformations and actions and doesn't use Dataframe as yet ( as per official documentation) , so it doesn't utilize Tungsten or Catalyst Optimizer for those.

This document below mentions all design consideration for Hive on Spark as available in official documentation -

[Hive on Spark Mode Design](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12652517/Hive-on-Spark.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the details. Do convert HQL queries/batches code into Spark SQL (or HiveContext) code improves the performance?

Comment: It depends what operations you are trying to do, and directly putting them in hiveContext might not be helpful in all cases, you will need to understand Spark internals to optimize and tune those in certain cases.